# Decimal to Base of Three System with a Twist

Tags: algorithm, radix

Everyone knows how to convert number from decimal system to binary. I also do. Everyone also knows how to convert from decimal to the base of three system.

However, I have a problem where I need to convert decimal number to a "strange base 3" system where one symbol cannot be the first one and should be surrounded by the remaining two. So, one symbol cannot be repeated before one of the other two has been used.

So, if "0" is the symbol that cannot be the first one and that cannot repeat:

perfectly legit numbers: 120, 110202, 1020

numbers that should not exist:
01212(zero should not be in the front), 120012 (zeros cannot repeat)

Can somebody, please, help to come up with an algorithm that converts from decimal system to this "strange base 3" system and back.

Thank you in advance

Comment: So then you need to give us an explanation of what values correspond.

Comment: So what will you do if a value can't be represented in your system?

Comment: Yes, a table of example conversions would be quite useful.  I'm not sure what system you are describing, or how certain numbers (such as 410) would be translated.  Are double-zeroed numbers just...skipped?  Or would a number like 410 not be translatable?

Comment: Hand wavy, brute force algorithm.
Generate the binary numbers:
0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, ...

then add a single 2 between each pair of digits and on the right in every possible way and add this to the binary list:
0 generates nothing
1 generates 12;
10 generates 102, 120;
11 generates 112, 121, 1212;
100 generates 1002, 1020, 10202, 1200, 12002, 12020, 120202;
...and so on.

Sort this mess to get an array whose decimal index will result in the strange base 3 number.

Comment: In a base 3 system, 1030 is not "perfectly legit", just as in binary (base 2), 12 is not legit.

Comment: This seems more like a 3-character encoding system than a "strange base 3".

Comment: @Chapso: Perhaps that is why it is called 'strange' base-3?

Comment: I think I sort of get what you are asking or.  It's counting base 3, but with the illegal numbers skipped.  However, I still don't understand why the number `1030` is valid.  Should it be `1020`?

Comment: What about converting to normal base 3 and just skipping all illegal numbers? The tricky part is then calculating how many numbers below a given number are illegal. The solution would become something like ConvertToBase3(n + IllegalNumbersBelow(n)) but there is still a twist - IllegalNumbersBelow(n) must actually return IllegalNumbersBelow(n + IllegalNumbersBelow(n)) and that might be quite tricky.

Comment: The requirement that one symbol cannot appear at the first position seems to be no problem - just assume that this symbol represents zero and then this requirement is equivalent to not performing any left zero padding and starting counting at one instead of zero.

Comment: There's a conflict in your requirements. You state that not only can one symbol not be repeated, but it must be surrounded by the remaining two. Why does that rule out numbers with leading zeros such as 01212 but not numbers with trailing zeros such as 120 and 1030? The trailing zeros only have the other symbols on one side, not surrounding them, just like the leading zeros.

Comment: @Moron: Right, I saw that explained in one of the answers.

Comment: @JAB: I tend to assume the specification is just not well formulated. I believe the intention is that one symbol must not be immediately repeated. To achieve this it must be surrounded by *any* of the two other symbols unless it occurs at the rightmost position.

Answer (score 0):

Is the following the desired mapping?

```
   0 <- illegal
   1               0
   2               1
  10               2
  11               3
  12               4
  20               5
  21               6
  22               7
 100 <- illegal                             
 101               8
 102               9
 110              10
 111              11
 112              12
 120              13
 121              14
 122              15
 200 <- illegal
 201              16
 202              17
 210              18
 211              19
 212              20
 220              21
 221              22
 222              23
1000 <- illegal
1001 <- illegal
1002 <- illegal
1010              24
1011              25
1012              26
1020              27
1021              28
1022              29
1100 <- illegal                             
1101              30
1102              31
1110              32
1111              33
1112              34
1120              35
1121              36
1122              37
1200 <- illegal
1201              38
1202              39
1210              40
1211              41
1212              42
1220              43
1221              44
1222              45
2000 <- illegal
```

Comment: I just assumed the three is a typo - else it would be base four.

Comment: Yes, this is the desired mapping

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Daniel's mapping, from Dec to strange-3-based:

```
x := n; // Original number
y:= 0;
do
  y0:= y;
  z:= DecToThree(x); // Convert x from Decimal to 3-based.
  y:= IllRep(z);     // Calculate the number y of numbers with at least 2 
                     // consecutive 0 with a representation in 3- based.
  x:= n + y;        // Add illegal representations to original number;
until (y = y0);
Result:= DezToThree(x); // Convert x from Decimal to 3-based.
```

Example:

> 16 -> 121 
>   y = 2 // {0, 100}
>
> 16+2 -> 200 
>   y = 3 // {0, 100, 200}
>
> 16+3-2 -> 201 
>   y = 3

The other way around:

```
y:= IllRep(x);     // calculate the number y of illegal representations
z:= ThreeToDec(x); // convert x from 3-based to dec 
result:= z-y;
```

Now all you need is a function that finds all illegal representations up to a certain number.

Comment: I also thought about your solution to use a loop to resolve the recursion  IllegalNumbersBelow(n) = IllegalNumbersBelow(n + IllegalNumbersBelow(n)). The obvious problem with this is that it will require more and more loop iterations when n grows.

Comment: @DanielBrückner - Leave it recursive and memoize it.